Convert .lyr file to raster qgis for zonal statistics?
I haven't come across anyone asking this issue or solutions - but I don't know how to obtain my zonal histogram and zonal statistics for this particular dataset, because the .lyr file is a vector file.
I tried running the rasterize (vector to raster) but I have no idea what to set the resolution, or if I'm supposed to use pixels or geo reference. I've tried looking this up but it seems something that is already given with the dataset. For instance, I have done zonal histograms before with raster tif files with no issue, and the dataset clearly said it was using pixels.
My goal is to essentially obtain the number of pixels for each land type found within a site and it's buffer zone on QGIS. Currently I am using QGIS version 3.36.2-Maidenhead.
ALso this is all the info this file gives me - doesn't give me any pixel info, so I can't add anything into the width/horizontal resolution and height/vertical resolution fields for rasterization.

And this is all I am able to set up so far for the rasterization. Stuck on the height/width and not sure what to put for fixed value to burn (or if it's needed).

